# Get content size of listview in flutter

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, listview, cardview

I am working on flutter project. I want to get content size of horizontal listview. When i click on option in list view , i want to check that option is in proper bound of screen or out of bound. If it is out of bound, then how to move in of bound?
Please suggest and help me to sort out

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the parent widget?

Comment: Yeasin Sheikh
 - List view with Card item with dynamic width accoridng to content of text

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ScrollController` to get the size of listView. If it is on Column widget, wrap with Expanded widget to get available space.

```dart
class _TDState extends State<XT> {
  late final ScrollController controller = ScrollController()
    ..addListener(() {
      print(controller.position.maxScrollExtent);
    });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
            controller: controller,
            itemCount: 44,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text("item $index"),
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks your answer. If click on particular index so how can i get the offset of that index in listview?

Comment: try wrap the item with tappable widget and use `controller.offset` or `controller.position.pixels`